# align background rectangle to center and behind the boxes

Tags: html, css

I want to create this:

[image]

So far I get really close:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.background-rectangle {

  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 


<div class="box-container">

<div class="subbox-container">

    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box1" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->


    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box2" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->

    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box3" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->

</div>

<!-- background rectangle -->
<div class="background-rectangle" style="height: 177.257px; width: 260.673px; transform: translate(-0.9479px, -0.9479px);">
    <svg height="176.30939999999998" width="162" viewBox="-1 -1 274 186" data-commandset-id="35">
        <g >
            <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.07" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

</div>





<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But I'm unable to position the background rectangle correctly...
How can I do that?

Thanks to @Rayees AC We are even closer now:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.background-rectangle {

  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box-container {
position: absolute;
top: 300px

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 


<div class="box-container">

<div class="subbox-container">

    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box1" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->


    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box2" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->

    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box3" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->

</div>

<!-- background rectangle -->
<div class="background-rectangle" style="height: 177.257px; width: 260.673px; z-index: 999999; transform: translate(139px, -252px);">
    <svg height="276.30939999999998" width="162" viewBox="-1 -1 274 186" data-commandset-id="35">
        <g >
            <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

</div>





<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But I still can't figure a way to bring the background rectangle to the right position **without touching width of elements**!

Comment: Why all these svg while you could just use plain css ?

Comment: I don't know how to rewrite it to plain css:( Does useing svgs make any problem or disadvantages?

Comment: they're mostly used for icons, this will be a pain to maintain

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely don't need svgs to achieve this, they're really unnecessary and will be a nightmare to maintain.
You should build these boxes by using plain html and css.

You'll need to change height width font-family and colors as you need though.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
    font-family: 'Heebo-Light', serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 200px;
    flex: 0 0 3rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(227,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.box + .box {
   margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

### Method - 1

---

you are `translate` position not correct of `background-rectangle`

```css
  @font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.background-rectangle {

  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

<div class="box-container">

<div class="subbox-container">

    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box1" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->


    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box2" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->

    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box3" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->

</div>

<!-- background rectangle -->
<div class="background-rectangle" style="height: 177.257px;width: 260.673px;transform: translate(-122.257px,84px);z-index: 999999;">
    <svg height="176.30939999999998" width="100%" viewBox="-1 -1 274 186" data-commandset-id="35">
        <g >
            <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.07" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

</div>





<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I changed style of `background-rectangle`

```
<div class="background-rectangle" style="height: 177.257px;width: 260.673px;transform: translate(-122.257px,84px);z-index: 999999;">
    <svg height="176.30939999999998" width="100%" viewBox="-1 -1 274 186" data-commandset-id="35">
        <g >
            <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.07" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

### Method -2

---

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.background-rectangle {

  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box-container {
position: absolute;
top: 300px

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 


<div class="box-container">

<div class="subbox-container">

    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box1" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->


    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box2" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->

    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box3" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655499999999996" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->

</div>

<!-- background rectangle -->
<div class="background-rectangle" style="height: 230px; width: 162px; transform: translate(139px, -79px);">
    <svg height="230" width="162" viewBox="-1 -1 274 186" data-commandset-id="35">
        <g >
            <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

</div>





<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please check @Sara Ree

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: All svg ```width``` makes ```100%```

Comment: Are you sure to reach your goal? @Sara Ree

Comment: I'm trying this... Thanks for the answer and plus one for now...